# c++ How can I insert into a std::list and keep the order using std library functions

Tags: c++, list

I have a sorted std::list and I want to use some standard library std::insert_sorted method to insert objects and preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard library method to do that. But you could write your own - it is just about iterating through the list until you find the right place to insert the new element.
Or you could consider using another container in place of list, e.g. a set or a map, if that is suitable.